# Loading resources from another bundle

Tags: cocoa, macos, bundle, nsbundle

If I have a bundle that contains a class and some resources used by that class. If I load the class from the bundle how should I load the resources(that are in the bundle where I loaded the class from) in that class?

Let's say I want to load an image inside my object instantiated from the class loaded from the bundle.
If I do

```
NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
```

Will it load the image that's inside the bundle from where I loaded the class from? or will it look in the bundle of the application that loaded the bundle with the class and resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This method searches for named images
>   in several places, returning the first
>   image it finds matching the given
>   name. The order of the search is as
>   follows:
>
> 1. Search for an object whose name was
>      set explicitly using the setName:
>      method and currently resides in the
>      image cache.
> 2. Search the application's
>      main bundle for a file whose name
>      matches the specified string. (For
>      information on how the bundle is
>      searched, see ““Accessing a Bundle's
>      Contents”“ in Bundle Programming
>      Guide.)
> 3. Search the Application Kit
>      framework for a shared image with the
>      specified name. When looking for files
>      in the application bundle, it is
>      better (but not required) to include
>      the filename extension in the name
>      parameter. [(Link)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: So how do you would you load it in this case? 1)doesn't apply because the image hasn't been loaded before(it's not in the cache) 2) doesn't apply since it's in a separate bundle not the main bundle 3) it's not an appkit framework.

Comment: Create an `NSBundle` instance. Get the file path. Load the image.

Comment: But I have an object which is instantiated from a class loaded from that bundle. Do I create an NSBundle instance of the same bundle in which the class is located and load the image from that bundle? If the class is inside a bundle how do I load the bundle which contains the class inside a method defined in that class?

Comment: @thealch3m1st: If you have an instance of a class from the bundle, the bundle already exists and is loaded. Attempting to instantiate the bundle again will give you the existing instance, and attempting to load it again will do nothing. @Alexsander's comment is the correct solution, and really should be the/another answer. For more details, look in the documentation for NSBundle in both Foundation and AppKit (AppKit adds the methods to find an image or sound within the bundle).

Answer (score 15):

On OS X 10.7+ do this do this:

```
NSBundle *otherBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier: @"com.company.otherapp"];
NSImage *imageFromOtherBundle = [otherBundle imageForResource: @"imageName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `+bundleForClass:` class method of `NSBundle` to get a reference to the bundle for a particular class.

You can then use the `‑pathForImageResource:` method of `NSBundle` to get the path to the image and create an `NSImage` with that path.